# Linq Sorting on list and its nested collection of same class

Tags: c#, list, linq, sorting

I have the following class

```
public class Node
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public string Symbol { get; set; }
    public string KaartNum { get; set; }
    public List<Node> children { get; set; }
}
```

It's a tree list, which holds the node within the node, I want to get the list ordered by `KaartNum`, then by `Name`, I tried the following for sorting to get the desired results.

```
List<Node> SortedList = obNodeList
  .OrderBy(o => Convert.ToInt16(o.Kaart))
  .ThenBy(o => o.Name))
  .ThenBy(c=>c.children.OrderBy(p=>p.N))
  .ToList();
```

It works only at root class level and not working on nested children
the property, I only need to sort on `Name` property.

Comment: I think it is not common to order a list depending on a list insisde it. What are you really trying to do please?

Comment: Just order the root list then foreach each root node, order the children?

Comment: Why should you give to a class a list of itself?

Comment: What is `p.N`? There is no `N` property defined on `Node`. Should that be `p.Name`?

Comment: @Marco Salerno, the OP is dealing with a hierarchical structure (tree) and therefore having a list of the same type (children) is common practice.

Comment: yes, sorry it should be p.Name..

Comment: @blins didn't read it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursion to the rescue:

```
List<Node> SortParents(List<Node> source) {
    if(source == null || source.Count == 0) return source;
    return 
        source
        .OrderBy(o => Convert.ToInt16(o.KaartNum))
        .ThenBy(o => o.Name)
        .Select(o => new Node() {
            Name = o.Name,
            Image = o.Image,
            Symbol = o.Symbol,
            KaartNum = o.KaartNum,
            children = SortChildren(o.children)
        })
        .ToList();
}
List<Node> SortChildren(List<Node> source) {
    if(source == null || source.Count == 0) return source;
    return 
        source
        .OrderBy(o => o.Name)
        .Select(o => new Node() {
            Name = o.Name,
            Image = o.Image,
            Symbol = o.Symbol,
            KaartNum = o.KaartNum,
            children = SortChildren(o.children)
        })
        .ToList();
}
```

You can merge both methods into one with an additional `bool sortOnlyByName` parameter if you want to.